# Listing orderings of n elements into k categories

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have n events {v1, ..., vn} that will occur upon some specific times {t1, ..., tk} where k <= n (multiple ones can occur at the same time), and I need to list each way in which this can occur.

For example, if we had 2 events, I could have:

{v1 < v2}, {v2 < v1} (2 times)

{v1 = v2} (1 time)

If we had 3 events, I could have all 6 orderings with 3 distinct times, plus

{v1 = v2 < v3}, {v1 = v3 < v2}, {v2 = v3 < v1}, {v1 < v2 = v3}, {v2 < v1 = v3}, {v3 < v1 = v2} (2 times)

{v1 = v2 = v3} (1 time)

So I don't actually want all possible groupings because {v1 = v2 < v3} is equivalent to {v2 = v1 < v3}, for example.

My thought is that I need to generate all of the permutations of the n events for the case where k=n anyway, which I have a method to do, so perhaps I could generate the possible categories on top of this and then prune out the duplicates, but I'm not sure how to check if, for example, {v3 = v4 = v2 < v1 = v6 < v5} is a duplicate of something we've accepted previously efficiently.

Perhaps it's possible to be more systematic when operating from the list of permutations and figure out how to drop duplicates without re-checking with the list we've archived so far?

I realize this isn't going to work in reasonable time for even moderately large numbers of events, but I would like to push it as high as possible, 6 would be okay, 8 or 10 even better.

I am using MATLAB, but I'm willing to pursue any language someone may suggest as optimal for such a problem, and any advice on general language-agnostic methodology is very welcome and appreciated.

Comment: If you're looking to just generate them, try generating for a fixed k. Then you know how many must be equal, so try all permutations of all these equal ones. Following that, you can permute accordingly for the ordering. That's language independent, but MATLAB isn't quite the best language for this. :)

Comment: Thanks, yeah, this is part of a mathematical problem I'm working on, hence MATLAB, but I can generate it with whatever and import it there for math stuff afterwards.

Comment: It might be most convenient to write a Java class for this, that way you can import it into MATLAB and call/use the class much easier than say, a compiled executable. Either that or a mex file.

Comment: If I fix k, I'll know only that I have k categories, which could be of any size (maximum n-k) and any order. So you suggest I fix the categories in each possible way and generate all distinct *combinations* in each category?

Or no... I should generate the combinations then permute the categories, I suppose?

Comment: Is the omission of `v1 < v2 < v3` and the like accidental or on purpose?

Comment: @Dukeling: He didn't omit them. He just abbreviated the description to: "I could have all 6 orderings with 3 distinct times"

Comment: @rici Oh right, it just took me a while to figure out what that sentence meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach (code follows):

Generate the permutations of `v1…vn` using any standard algorithm (there are n! permutations, obviously). For each permutation `vp1…vpn` enumerate all of the possible formulae:

`vp1 R1 vp2 R2 vp3 … Rn-1 vpn`

where `Ri` can always be `<` and can also be `=` if `pi < pi+1`.

For example, if n is 3:

```
v1 v2 v3: v1 < v2 < v3; v1 < v2 = v3; v1 = v2 < v3; v1 = v2 = v3
v1 v3 v2: v1 < v3 < v2; v1 = v3 < v2
v2 v1 v3: v2 < v1 < v3; v2 < v1 = v3
v2 v3 v1: v2 < v3 < v1; v2 = v3 < v1
v3 v1 v2: v3 < v1 < v2; v3 < v1 = v2
v3 v2 v1: v3 < v2 < v1
```

You can do the enumeration of relationships recursively (which was effectively how I did it above, by hand).

**Edit:** This is Sloane sequence [A000670](http://oeis.org/A000670), the link contains a variety of possible useful references. For n=9, the count is 7087261 which seems eminently practical; for n=10, it's 102247563 which is easily within the bounds of modern desktop computation. (I don't know about matlab, though).

Here's a python implementation:

```
def rels(perm):
  if len(perm) == 1:
    yield perm
  else:
    for p in rels(perm[1:]):
      yield (perm[0], '<') + p
      if perm[0] < perm[1]:
        yield (perm[0], '=') + p

def orders(n):
  return reduce(lambda a,b:a+b,
                [[i for i in rels(p)] for p in itertools.permutations(range(n))])

>>> print '\n'.join(map(repr,[o for o in orders(4)]))
(0, '<', 1, '<', 2, '<', 3)
(0, '=', 1, '<', 2, '<', 3)
(0, '<', 1, '=', 2, '<', 3)
(0, '=', 1, '=', 2, '<', 3)
(0, '<', 1, '<', 2, '=', 3)
(0, '=', 1, '<', 2, '=', 3)
(0, '<', 1, '=', 2, '=', 3)
(0, '=', 1, '=', 2, '=', 3)
(0, '<', 1, '<', 3, '<', 2)
(0, '=', 1, '<', 3, '<', 2)
(0, '<', 1, '=', 3, '<', 2)
(0, '=', 1, '=', 3, '<', 2)
(0, '<', 2, '<', 1, '<', 3)
(0, '=', 2, '<', 1, '<', 3)
(0, '<', 2, '<', 1, '=', 3)
(0, '=', 2, '<', 1, '=', 3)
(0, '<', 2, '<', 3, '<', 1)
(0, '=', 2, '<', 3, '<', 1)
(0, '<', 2, '=', 3, '<', 1)
(0, '=', 2, '=', 3, '<', 1)
(0, '<', 3, '<', 1, '<', 2)
(0, '=', 3, '<', 1, '<', 2)
(0, '<', 3, '<', 1, '=', 2)
(0, '=', 3, '<', 1, '=', 2)
(0, '<', 3, '<', 2, '<', 1)
(0, '=', 3, '<', 2, '<', 1)
(1, '<', 0, '<', 2, '<', 3)
(1, '<', 0, '=', 2, '<', 3)
(1, '<', 0, '<', 2, '=', 3)
(1, '<', 0, '=', 2, '=', 3)
(1, '<', 0, '<', 3, '<', 2)
(1, '<', 0, '=', 3, '<', 2)
(1, '<', 2, '<', 0, '<', 3)
(1, '=', 2, '<', 0, '<', 3)
(1, '<', 2, '<', 0, '=', 3)
(1, '=', 2, '<', 0, '=', 3)
(1, '<', 2, '<', 3, '<', 0)
(1, '=', 2, '<', 3, '<', 0)
(1, '<', 2, '=', 3, '<', 0)
(1, '=', 2, '=', 3, '<', 0)
(1, '<', 3, '<', 0, '<', 2)
(1, '=', 3, '<', 0, '<', 2)
(1, '<', 3, '<', 0, '=', 2)
(1, '=', 3, '<', 0, '=', 2)
(1, '<', 3, '<', 2, '<', 0)
(1, '=', 3, '<', 2, '<', 0)
(2, '<', 0, '<', 1, '<', 3)
(2, '<', 0, '=', 1, '<', 3)
(2, '<', 0, '<', 1, '=', 3)
(2, '<', 0, '=', 1, '=', 3)
(2, '<', 0, '<', 3, '<', 1)
(2, '<', 0, '=', 3, '<', 1)
(2, '<', 1, '<', 0, '<', 3)
(2, '<', 1, '<', 0, '=', 3)
(2, '<', 1, '<', 3, '<', 0)
(2, '<', 1, '=', 3, '<', 0)
(2, '<', 3, '<', 0, '<', 1)
(2, '=', 3, '<', 0, '<', 1)
(2, '<', 3, '<', 0, '=', 1)
(2, '=', 3, '<', 0, '=', 1)
(2, '<', 3, '<', 1, '<', 0)
(2, '=', 3, '<', 1, '<', 0)
(3, '<', 0, '<', 1, '<', 2)
(3, '<', 0, '=', 1, '<', 2)
(3, '<', 0, '<', 1, '=', 2)
(3, '<', 0, '=', 1, '=', 2)
(3, '<', 0, '<', 2, '<', 1)
(3, '<', 0, '=', 2, '<', 1)
(3, '<', 1, '<', 0, '<', 2)
(3, '<', 1, '<', 0, '=', 2)
(3, '<', 1, '<', 2, '<', 0)
(3, '<', 1, '=', 2, '<', 0)
(3, '<', 2, '<', 0, '<', 1)
(3, '<', 2, '<', 0, '=', 1)
(3, '<', 2, '<', 1, '<', 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, something like this occurred to me, but I'm not sure how you are avoiding duplicates? What is being done recursively exactly? (In words is fine, I can figure out a code if I get the idea.)

Comment: There are no duplicates because the equivalence classes are being generated in canonical order (by increasing event index). It should be clear that the `<` sequences cannot repeat between two permutations of vi. I wrote the recursion in python, for what it's worth; I'll attach it to the answer in a second.

Comment: @mach: there you go. a complete running program, with example output.